# How can I ask my cat to bring me something?

Tags: cats, training, communication, hunting

Last night my cat brought in a mouse right before I was going to sleep, and I tried to save it but failed. She killed the creature, and then gave it to me. It was really cute.

I thought it was really kind of her to bring me a dead mouse, and I want to take a picture of the dead animal when she's got it with her and hasn't given it to me. I let her suck my pyjamas or whatever, and I gave her a bit of wet food in an effort to bribe her into getting me another so I could photograph it, but nothings working.

Is it possible for me to ask my cat to bring me a dead thing? I want her to bring me one every day now, and I want my house to be littered in corpses that I can take out.

Comment: The cat seems to have noticed that you are not a very good hunter.  Also FYI: Be careful what you wish for.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to train you cat to do tricks. It will take considerably longer than with a dog because you first have to convince the cat that learning is worth the effort.

However, the only way I can think of to teach her to hunt for you us to reward her when she brings something home, and to increase her opportunities to find things to bring home (which may require training her with some sort of lure). Or to just work on "bring it here" -- which is a difficult concept for some cats.

What you've been doing won't work because she isn't connecting her action with the reward.

And not all cats are dedicated hunters, especially if they aren't hungry.

Comment: "It will take considerably longer than with a dog because you first have to convince the cat that learning is worth the effort." This is technically incorrect, some breeds of cats are very interested in pleasing their owners. Depends on the breed. That said, some dogs think they are smarter than their human and don't need to do anything besides crap on the rug and bite your friends when they come to the door. Experience is from my 17 year old yellow lab/ golden retreiver mut and my 13 year old Rag Doll breed.

Comment: Agreed, some breeds tend to be more focused on their humans, and there's individual variation. But as a rule of thumb... There seem to be good reasons professional animal-actor trainers often cite cats in general as more challenging.

Answer (score 0):

My cats bring me cat toys from around the house, such as fuzzy balls, fake mice, fake feathers, etc. They also get into my hair ties and bring those to me too. This is their form of indoor hunting. Maybe if you get your cat some toys, she will naturally collect them and bring them to you. It may not give you the satisfaction of having your house littered with corpses(!!!), but it will give the cat the satisfaction of hunting even when she may not be hungry enough to hunt an actual edible creature.

Answer (score 0):

Some breeds are more interested in pleasing their owners, this is usually due to breeding. That said most cats only do what they want to do. You need to find a way to convince her it's what she wants.

My Ragdoll, Dr. Mittens is extremely food driven and as much as she likes food, she needs pets and playtime. When she does what I like, I treat her... immediately. Using a clicker consistently might also help.

When she does something good, use the clicker and treat her immediately. Eventually, their mouth will water at the sound of the clicker and they will often then start rotating through the different things trying anything to get that treat.